# What is the difference between set_false_path Vs. set_clock_group?

Tags: synthesis

I've got a question about the Design compiler's constraints.
Especially, set_false_path Vs. set_clock_group.

As I know,

1. set_false_path

> (a) set_false_path -from [get_clocks CLKA] -to [get_clocks CLKB]].

I think this is considering about one way direction.

> (b) set_false_path -from [get_clocks CLKA] -to [get_clocks CLKB]]
>
> set_false_path -from [get_clocks CLKB] -to [get_clocks CLKA]]
>
> -> CLKA -> CLKB, CLKB -> CLKA (Bi-Direction)

2. set_clock_groups

> (a) set_clock_groups -asynchronous -group CLKA -group CLKB

I think this is considering about Bi-direction.

So here is my question
I think there is only difference between set_false_path and set_clock_group is only direction.

Then I think 1.(b) and 2.(a) are the same. so then can I use 2.(a) instead 1.(b)?

Answer (score 3):

In some cases (like 1b and 2a) both commands have the same results, so the user can prefer any of them. But there are also some differences for some cases.

`set_false_path` allows to remove specific constraints between clocks. For example, I can remove setup checks while keeping hold checks. Or I can select only one edge (rise or fall) of the clock(s). This command has more options shortly.

```
set_false_path -rise_from CLKA -fall_to CLKB -setup
```

The advantage of `set_clock_groups` is simple. It saves us from defining too many false paths. That's why 2a is better than 1b. If we have more clocks, it will help much more.

```
set_clock_groups -asynchronous -group CLKA -group CLKB -group CLKC
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that set_false_path has the highest precedence in SDC files, so it trumps all other constraints. Whereas set_clock_groups can be overridden if you, for example, want to constrain a sampled clock domain crossing (e.g. CDC FIFO Gray code crossing).